# Definition of subobject classifier in presheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory, pullback, topos-theory

I am reading Awodey (Category Theory, 1st edition), p 175, and I have difficulties to understand the paragraph about the subobject classifier of $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C^{op}}}$.

First let me quote the paragraph. Awodey is trying to define a subobject classifier $1 \rightarrow \Omega$ by using sieves:

> Let
>   $$ \Omega(C) = \{ S\subseteq
> > \mathbf{C}_1 \mid S \text{ is a sieve
> > on } C \} $$
>
> and given $h:D \rightarrow C$ let
>
> $$ h^* : \Omega(C)\rightarrow\Omega(D)
> > $$
>
> be defined by
>
> $$ h^*(S)=\{g:\cdot \rightarrow D \mid
> > h \circ g \in S  \} $$
>
> This clearly defines a preasheaf
>   $\Omega : \mathbf{C^{op}} \rightarrow
> > \mathbf{Sets}$, with a distinguished
>   point,
>
> $$ t:1\rightarrow\Omega $$
>
> namely, at each $C$, the "total sieve"
>
> $$ t_C = \{ f : \cdot \rightarrow C\}
> > $$
>
> We claim that $t:1\rightarrow \Omega$
>   so defined is a subobject classifier
>   for $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C^{op}}}$.
>   Indeed, given any object $E$ and a
>   subobject $U \rightarrow E$, define $u
> > : E \rightarrow \Omega$ at any object
>   $C \in \mathbf{C}$ by:
>
> $$ u_C(e) = \{f:D\rightarrow C \mid
> > f^*(e) \in U(D) \rightarrowtail E(D)
> > \} $$
>
> for any $e \in E(C)$. That is,
>   $u_C(e)$ is the sieve of arrows into
>   $C$ that take $e \in E(C)$ back into
>   the subobject $U$.

At this point I am very troubled by the notation $f^*(e)$.

If I assume it is a pullback notation, being the pullback functor of $f$ applied on the element $e$, I end up with this diagram:

$$
\begin{matrix}
&\xrightarrow{} & 1 \\[1ex]
\downarrow \rlap{\scriptstyle{f^*(e)}} & & \downarrow \rlap{\scriptstyle{e}} \\[1ex]
&\xrightarrow{f} & E(C) \\[1ex]
\end{matrix}
$$

that seems to me totally crazy because $f$ is supposed to be of the type $f:D\rightarrow C$.

Could somebody show me what I missed?

Note: If possible, could you avoid using adjoints in your answers? Just because I have not yet reached the chapter when it is defined and explained... (other notions are ok)

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is that, since $E$ is a contravariant functor to $\mathbf{Sets}$, by definition $f:D \to C$ induces a map of sets $f^*:E(C) \to E(D)$.  Then $u_C(e)$ consists of the arrows $f$ such that $f^*(e)$ actually lands in the subobject $U(D)$ of $E(D)$.  You can then check that this is a sieve for each $e$, and so on.

It might be helpful to let $E$ be a representable functor, say $E = \mathbf{C}(-,X)$.  Then $e$ is a map $C \to X$, $U(D)$ is a set of maps $D \to X$, and $u_C(e)$ is the set of maps $D \to C$ such that the composition $D \to C \stackrel{e}{\to} X$ is in the set $U(D)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate very much your example. It shows why the notation $f^*$ has been used, acting by precomposition on the map $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't $f^{*}(e)$ just the action of the functor $E$ on morphisms, i.e., it could be written instead as $E(f)(e)$? Perhaps Steve can confirm in person.

Comment: Steve says the first edition has a rather unfortunate number of typos.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! With your definition $f^∗=E(f)$, it works. I have also the 2nd edition in book version (the 1st ed. is my portative electronic edition), and the notations are the same for this paragraph ($f^∗$). 